# Why is my json_encode not working

Tags: php, json

why is this `json_encode` not working. It was working when I had two values in the array but now with three it just shows nothing.

Using `json_last_error` in json_encode shows this error:

```
Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in
```

This is the array:

```
[8000] => Array
    (
        [employee_id] => AAAAA
        [name] => tom  
        [tick] => 1
    )

[8001] => Array
    (
        [employee_id] => BBBB
        [name] => harry
        [tick] => 1
    )

[8002] => Array
    (
        [employee_id] => CCCC
        [name] => sam
        [tick] => 1
    )

[8003] => Array
    (
        [employee_id] => DDD
        [name] => ricky
        [tick] => 1
    )
```

This is the json encode code `$datas` is the array:

```
$json = json_encode($datas, json_last_error);

var_dump($json);
```

Comment: quite clearly `json_last_error` is not an integer

Comment: I'd suggest you read the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). `json_last_error` is not a valid option for the second parameter.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I was just using that to show me the error, if I use just the array $datas I get nothing

Comment: Then use one of the values pointed out by @aynber

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes this works thanks I needed to add the depth. One thing can I add two options to it? I need to add JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK but adding it as a third parameter is returning a string

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca got it need to pipe it.

Comment: @aynber if you include that as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1):

[`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/json_last_error) is a function, not an [option](http://php.net/json_encode).

```
$json = json_encode($datas); 
$error = json_last_error(); 
if ($error == JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
   var_dump($json);
}
```